# UUID for a page content in AEM across author and it's associated publish servers are different

Tags: aem, uuid, hashcode, jcr, hash-code-uniqueness

A page in author with UUID(jcr:uuid) is activated and its content is replicated onto the 3 associated publish servers.
The content available in all the 3 publish servers has different UUIDs. So, considering the same content across all the 4 instances on AEM (1 author + 3 publish), how to associate with something unique?

I'm implementing a solution where I need to associate a unique id that can be mapped to the individual content across all the instances.

Approaches that I've tried till now:

1. Used the content path - to generate a unique id - by removing the '/' & '-' in the path.
   **The issue faced** - For some paths this can be more than 128 chars which is the limit for the service to accept a unique id.
2. If I generate a unique id programmatically it will work, but how can I try to use that to track the back content? As I cannot store this programmatically created id on the jcr:content and activate the page.
   **Issues** - If I replicate the page, it will change the activation date as well- which is also important metadata for the content.

What can be the most feasible solution for the use case? Kindly help with suggestions and possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash of the content path. Easiest way to get a hash is using  `hashCode()`. For compactness, use the Base64 representation of the hash bytes and truncate after a predetermined number of chars.

Comment: To create a unique id for each page, if we truncate the hashed value created using the path, can there be a scenario that 2 different page paths can have the same unique id?

If it is always going to be less than 128 chars, by default, that would be fine to implement.

Comment: By referring to some theories online, 2 different string values(page path) can have the same hash value. 
This solution may fail in that case, as I can override a page's metadata mapping to another page's hash code.

Comment: Many hash implementations give you 128 bits – much less than 128 chars. Even if you take SHA-512, which gives you 512 bits (64 bytes), you’ll have plenty of space left over. Base64 has an overhead of 33% so the hash will be 86 chars in length.
Also, yes, hash collisions are a thing but unless you specifically worry about attacks (and are hashing attacker-controlled data), they are unlikely enough (especially for reasonably short strings like jcr paths) that you shouldn’t need to concern yourself with them.